# Microsoft Graph / Outlook REST; what is the process to get the application live/public available for use by our customers and how long does it take?

Tags: rest, api, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

In our experience with other APIs there is usually a test/private mode and then after the app is approved it can go into live/public mode.

After we create an application based on Microsoft Graph / Outlook REST, what is the process to get the application live/public available for use by our customers and how long does it take? Or is it already live?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really specific, so I'll just answer the general question.

Everybody can create an application for the Microsoft cloud. There isn't a test environment, so every application is live the moment you create it (and switch on multi-tenant). It is always up to the user (or tenant admin) to grant your application access!

Microsoft does however offer various ways to get your application under the attention of a much larger audience. And to get your application in such a marketplace they have various review/test/... processes in place.